# Time on server since client sent packet

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a game with a client and server, and am trying to figure out a way to tell the amount of time from a client sending a packet and the server receiving it (so I can check where the enemies were at that point).

I attempted sending

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(1969)).TotalMilliseconds
```

With then client, then just check that same value on the server when it recieves the packet, and subtract them, but the issue with this is that timezones could completely break this, if the client and server are on different timezones. Also it seemed not the most accurate.

Is there a "proper" way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well sending the epoch time will not account for leap seconds, but timezone changes should not be affected if you use `DateTime.UtcNow` and do all processing in UTC. Using this method would allow for users to manipulate that number, since it is based of of the computers time setting. There is not real proper way to handle this. Look at many games with latency issues. This occurs for both clientside and server-side processing.

The other issue with this method, depending on the type of game, is that the reaction of a user depends on events in real time. So if you reverse time for a calculation, the result of that could have affected another players actions.

For a complex handling, [I think the game 'Eve online' will slow down 'Game Time' for large fights.](https://community.eveonline.com/news/dev-blogs/introducing-time-dilation-tidi/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, however, as long as I have the time from client sending packet to server receiving, that will do for me. My game is PvE, and the client handles collisions. (So when the client detects a collision, it sends to the server the collision, and then the server looks at that enemy, looks at where it was when that collision occurred, and sees if the collision is valid). Since my game isn't PvP, I don't have to deal with anything to do with other players.

Comment: @user183106 in that case you could just use `DateTime.UtcNow` on both the client and the server. that time is coordinated, and no need to base it on a certain year.